# hierarchical filtering in Jackson

Tags: jackson

I have a configuration file that can have the following lines:
    exclude employee.dept.*
    include student.dept.*

So based on the values in that file I need to suppress or include those properties in the serialized JSON. I looked at implementing BeanPropertyFilter but that doesn't give me details about the parent node, i.e., I only know that I am serializing dept.deptCode but I don't know the parent of the dept node, which could be either employee or student. Any idea how to achieve that functionality?

Comment: I've posted answer to similar question.
[Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036366/filter-nested-objects-using-jacksons-beanpropertyfilter/37859357#37859357)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to use the Tree Model; that is, to read JSON as `JsonNode`:

```
JsonNode root = new ObjectMapper().readTree(jsonSource);
```

and then handle filtering. Trying to use data-binding using configuration file is probably more difficult way to tackle this.

Note that you can easily convert between `JsonNode` and POJO types, as necessary:

```
MyObject ob = mapper.treeToValue(root, MyObject.class);
JsonNode tree = mapper.valueToTree(ob);
```

so that transformations and translations can be done using JSON trees, but you can still use POJOs as source or target.