# Exclude properties from Json data without deserializing it

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have Json data like this:

```
{
"_id": "123",
"transaction": {
    "className": "ExpenseReport",
    "id": "789",
    "createdBy": {
        "firstName": "Donald",
        "lastName": "Morgan",
        "address": {
            "street1": "1362 Woodlawn Lane",
            "street2": "Suite #100805",
            "place": {
                "city": "Darien",
                "state": "CA",
                "country": "USA",
                "number": "OBJ-4823478",
                "createdBy": "Brett Wright"
            },
            "zip": 88884,
            "number": "OBJ-5740231",
            "createdBy": "Brett Wright"
        },
        "number": "OBJ-3561551",
        "createdBy": "Brett Wright"
    },
    "score": 12,
    "reasonCodes": [
        "these",
        "are",
        "strings"
    ]
}
}
```

I want a subset of this data after excluding some properties, say something like this:

```
{
"_id": "123",
"transactionType": "EXPENSE_REPORT",
"transaction": {
    "className": "ExpenseReport",
    "id": "789",
    "createdBy": {
        "firstName": "Donald",
        "lastName": "Morgan",
        "address": {
            "street1": "1362 Woodlawn Lane",
            "street2": "Suite #100805",
            "place": {
                "city": "Darien",
                "state": "CA",
                "country": "USA"
            },
            "createdBy": "Brett Wright"
        },
        "createdBy": "Brett Wright"
    },
    "score": 12
}
}
```

Now one way would be to **deserialize** the original json data into a POJO, use [Jackson Views](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews) to annotate the required properties, and then serialize the same POJO again to get the Json data without the properties.

But I want to achieve something like this **WITHOUT DESERIALIZING** the Json data, say by just parsing the json data and removing the key-value pairs if they are not found in a collection. Is anyone aware of any library that does that?

Comment: "WITHOUT DESERIALIZING": Is there any reason why you would want to be implementing your own parser when there are perfectly nice JSON parsers there, or is this just a trick question? If you are making unreasonably-sounding restrictions, it is generally a good idea to explain why you think it is not, in fact, an unreasonable restriction.

Comment: Say I do not have access to the class corresponding to the Json data where I can create views and put annotations. This is definitely not a trick question.

Comment: So use a JSON parser that creates abstract JSON objects, without binding them to specific classes, like GSON.

Comment: (Without any personal experience with Jackson) it seems that Jackson also can do an [untyped mapping](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#A.22Raw.22_Data_Binding_Example) by providing `Map.class` as the target class. They call it "raw" or "untyped" data binding.

Comment: That is good, But I have one more constraint, I have to do all of this dynamically. For example, I have I get a list of properties I have to extract and I have the Json data of unknown structure. I have to parse it and include only the required properties

Comment: Why is that a "but"? Deserialize into an untyped structure, recurse and find properties you don't like, kill them with fire, reserialize.

Comment: My last comment was for your previous comment. I think untyped data binding would do my job. Thank you.

Comment: @Amadan *Parsing* (handling JSON as a data format) and *deserializing* (putting the JSON into a POJO) are two steps of a process. jackson does indeed expose both steps via its API. There is no need for workarounds to get only the *parsed* JSON data, the methods are all there.

Comment: @dhke: As I said, I have never used Jackson myself, which is why you're answering and I'm just commenting. Thanks for the details.

Comment: @Amadan All is well. I just wanted to indicate the two-step process, because I though there was a little confusion (i.e. what exactly is meant by *parsing* and *deserializing*) here.

Comment: @dhke: Well, yeah, given that JSON is a serialisation of JS arrays and objects (hashmaps), to me "deserialisation" is the inevitable result of parsing (unless you have a parsing library that simply tells you "valid" or "invalid"). Whether you deserialise into `JsonNode` or to `Map`, it's all deserialisation to me (and in languages I normally use, "POJO" is not a thing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jackson allows you to do only the parsing step using [`ObjectMapper.readTree()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readTree(java.io.InputStream))

```
JsonNode root = om.readTree(input);
```

The resulting `JsonNode`s are mutable, so something like this does the job:

```
ObjectNode place = (ObjectNode)(root.findPath("transaction")
    .findPath("createdBy")
    .findPath("address")
    .findPath("place")
);
place.remove("number");
```

This is --unfortunately-- not too nice, but can be easily wrapped into a generic method that takes a property path:

```
void deleteProperty(JsonNode root, List<String> propPath)
{
   JsonNode node = root;

   for (String propName: propPath.subList(0, propPath.size() - 1)) {
       node = node.findPath(propName);
   }
   // completely ignore missing properties
   if ((! node.isMissingNode()) && (! node.isEmpty())) {
       if (node instanceof ObjectNode) {
           final ObjectNode parent = (ObjectNode)node;
           parent.remove(propPath.get(propPath.size() - 1));
       }
   }
}
```

It is then possible to write out the modified node tree using [`writeTree()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#writeTree%28com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator,%20com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode%29).

There is also the [property filter API](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureJsonFilter). Unfortunately while it is easy to filter out individual properties with it, it is [non-trivial to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036366/filter-nested-objects-using-jacksons-beanpropertyfilter) for property paths. For example, in your case, the trivial filter can only filter out *all* `createdBy` properties.

Comment: Your solution seems fine to me. Just a side-note. I think I will need a POJO for applying the Jackson filter, which is one of my constraints

Comment: yes this did the job. Just curious. If I had a POJO instantiated with this data and a list of properties to be included, will I be able to get the trimmed json data directly?

Comment: You can attach `@JsonView(viewInterface)` annotations to the properties you want to serialize and set [`DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html#DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION) (kind of easy to overlook that one) on the `ObjectMapper`. You get a suitable writer via [`writerWithView()`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#writerWithView%28java.lang.Class%29). This then only writes the annotated properties.

Comment: As I mentioned before, I do not have the liberty to add annotations to the class. I only have the instance of the class. I was looking at Json Filter, which you mentioned in your answer. That would have been my knight in shining armor (it requires me to add only one annotation `@JsonFilter` which I can manage) but that would not work for more complex objects (if two inner beans have properties with the same name)